# Как получить значение перечисления по индексу в enum?

Tags: c#, enum

Есть перечисление. Можно ли получить его значение по индексу?

Comment: Индекс - это что имеется ввиду? Порядковый номер в коде?

Comment: А почему бы не попробовать  сделать эксперимент?

Comment: да, порядковый номер

Comment: *порядковый номер в коде*? Зачем? Сомневаюсь, что это возможно

Comment: если для enum-а не заданы явно значения (или они заданы по возрастанию) - то через Enum.GetValues. иначе - никак.

Comment: Индекс это номер по порядку, но заметьте, что может быть ситуация где номер по порядку и числовое значение разные, так как в enum можно произвольно задавать числовые значения. это не критика, просто говорю что есть такая возможность.

Comment: @PashaPash: У меня получилось, но дико извращённым способом. В production я бы такой код не взял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Например:

```
public enum Days{Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

После выполнения следующего кода, переменная day будет содержать значение Tue:

```
Days day=(Days)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days)).GetValue(3);
```

Comment: Не всегда можно. Такой вариант уже не пройдёт: `public enum Days { Sat = 2, Sun=4, Mon=1, Tue=3, Wed, Thu, Fri };` (см. комментарий @PashaPash)

Comment: @AK Согласен с этим.

Answer (score 4):

Если посмотреть в [сгенерированный IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgBgATIIwG4CwAUIcgMzoCmAdgK4C26AIgIYCeAzugN7oDKTw6ALzoATFF7VKQ9ABZxAWQD2U4VnEAVauWklxAdXIwNAC2riAYgCcw6AL74CQA=), можно увидеть, что поля, представляющие собой значения, располагаются в текстуальном порядке. Вытащив их с помощью рефлексии, получим сам текстуальный порядок.

Например:

```
public enum Days { Sat = 2, Sun = 4, Mon = 1, Tue = 3, Wed, Thu, Fri };
```

```
var fields = typeof(Days).GetFields().Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral);
string[] fieldNames = fields.Select(fi => fi.Name).ToArray();
Day[] fieldValues = fields.Select(fi => fi.GetRawConstantValue()).Cast<Days>().ToArray();
```

Теперь получение по индексу выглядит так:

```
string name = fieldNames[i];
Days day = fieldValues[i];
```

---

Я не знаю, гарантирован ли порядок полей и само их наличие в классе. В моей версии .NET (Microsoft .NET 4.7.1) это работает. Я бы, однако, не писал код, зависящий от точного порядка значений в enum'е.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно таким образом:

```
public enum Operation {Add = 0, Subtract = 3, Multiply = 1, Divide}

Operation Op = Enum.GetName(typeof(Operation),2);
Operation Op2 = Enum.GetName(typeof(Operation),3);
```

В переменной Op будет помещено Divide, а в Op2 Subtract.